# Convert date format from mysql TIMESTAMP help

Tags: php, mysql, html

have one problem, I need the dates in Swedish format, for instance, october is in swedish oktober... How can I do this?

This works so far for english dates:

```
      $date = date( "j F", strtotime( $row[insert_date] ) );
```

$display_table .= "$date";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help:

```
$date = date( "j F", strtotime( $row[insert_date] ) );
$display_table .= "<td width='67' rowspan='2'>$date</td>";
```

Comment: how about swedish dates? october in swedish is oktober... is there a simple way to solve this?

Comment: @camran - Set the locale before performing the query: "SET lc_time_names = 'sv_SE';"

Comment: update to my last comment, that is assuming you are using my solution posted, not Rudisimo's

Comment: is there a way to check if a letter in the script you gave me rudismo, has a value...?
example: if $date = october then = oktober?

Comment: @Rudisimo, that functionality is already built in to PHP with strftime(): http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php. I feel the my mysql solution is simpler however as it negates the need for all of these php function calls

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Rudisimo's answer is making mysql do the work for you:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`insert_date`,'%d %M') AS insert_date FROM `table_name` WHERE [...]
```

Comment: please explain more about this... 

Im currently using fetch array in a while loop for my table... 

give me some hints please

Comment: You just need to add the following into your SQL statement: "DATE_FORMAT(`insert_date`,'%d %M') AS insert_date". That will override the value for $row[insert_date] with a formatted version of the date. You won't need to adjust anything else in your php code